# Pass JavaScript code to textfield Django and display in template

Tags: django

If I wanted to have a textfield on a model and pass JavaScript code into it to display in the templates. How could I do this in a safe manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already automatically escapes everything passed to the template. Unless you specifically use `mark_safe` or turn autoescaping off, you are safe.